# Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Database\BaseResult::getResult()

Tags: codeigniter-4

> Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Database\BaseResult::getResult()

the following is the code for my controller and model

> **the contollers section**

```
namespace Modules\FrontEndBlog\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use Modules\FrontEndBlog\Models\ModelBlog as ModelBlog;
use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;

class Blog extends BaseController
{   
    protected $session;
    protected $ModelBlog;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->session = service('session');

        $this->ModelBlog = new ModelBlog();

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $pager = \Config\Services::pager();

        $blog = $this->ModelBlog->get_blog(1);
        dd($blog);
        $data = [
            'breadcrumbs' => 'Blog List',
            'blog' => $blog,
            'pager' => $this->ModelBlog->pager,
        ];

        return view('Modules\FrontEndBlog\Views\blog',$data);
    }


}
```

> **the models section**

```
namespace Modules\FrontEndBlog\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
 
class ModelBlog extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blog';
    protected $useTimestamps = 'true';

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(){
        
        $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();

    }

    public function get_blog($blog_page){

        return $this
        ->table('blog')
        ->select('blog.created_at as tgl_post, blog.random as random_blog, nama_kategori, nama_tags, nama_blog, fullname,content_blog,slug_blog, thumbnail')
        ->join('kategori_blog', 'kategori_blog.id=blog.id_kategori', 'left')
        ->join('tags_blog', 'tags_blog.id=blog.id_tags', 'left')
        ->join('users', 'users.id=blog.id_user', 'left')
        ->paginate($blog_page);
        

    }

}
```

> how to make pagination codeigniter 4, but model with class method. I
> tried but failed, I need a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but may be helpful for others.
remove __construct() function from Model class.